# EL 7.2 failing to run customization with open-vm-tools 9.10

Tags: redhat, vmware-tools, vmware-vcloud-director

Has anyone succeeded in running guest customizations with EL (RHEL or CentOS) 7.2 guests?

The system is VMware vCloud Director 5.6.5 and VMware ESXi 5.5.

v7.2 comes with open-vm-tools 9.10.2, which is supposed to include all necessary VMware Tools equivalents.

I have tried setting /etc/redhat-release to the 7.0 string. I have installed perl. I have not attempted to downgrade to older open-vm-tools + vmware-deployPkg because I would like to stick with 7.2 packages.

Here's some output...

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo)

[root@localhost ~]# which perl
/usr/bin/perl

[root@localhost ~]# vmware-toolbox-cmd -v
9.10.2.48224 (build-2822639)

[root@localhost ~]# cat /var/log/vmware-imc/toolsDeployPkg.log 
## Starting deploy pkg operation
Deploying /tmp/vmware-root/709d2d0c/cust93117962197543457.cab
Initializing deployment module. 

Cleaning old state file from tmp directory. 

EXIT STATE INPROGRESS 

Setting deploy error: Error removing lock /tmp/.vmware-deploy.INPROGRESS (No such file or directory) 

EXIT STATE Done 

Setting deploy error: Error removing lock /tmp/.vmware-deploy.Done (No such file or directory) 

EXIT STATE ERRORED 

Setting deploy error: Error removing lock /tmp/.vmware-deploy.ERRORED (No such file or directory) 

Setting deploy error: Success. 

Deploying cabinet file /tmp/vmware-root/709d2d0c/cust93117962197543457.cab. 

Transitioning from state (null) to state INPROGRESS. 

ENTER STATE INPROGRESS 

Reading cabinet file /tmp/vmware-root/709d2d0c/cust93117962197543457.cab. 

Creating directory /tmp
Creating directory /tmp/.vmware
Creating directory /tmp/.vmware/linux
Creating directory /tmp/.vmware/linux/deploy
Extracting package files. 

Launching deployment /usr/bin/perl -I/tmp/.vmware/linux/deploy/scripts /tmp/.vmware/linux/deploy/scripts/Customize.pl /tmp/.vmware/linux/deploy/cust.cfg. 

Command to exec : /usr/bin/perl 

sizeof ProcessInternal is 56

## Starting deploy pkg operation
Deploying /tmp/vmware-root/709d2d0c/cust93117962197543457.cab
Initializing deployment module. 

Cleaning old state file from tmp directory. 

EXIT STATE INPROGRESS 

Setting deploy error: Error removing lock /tmp/.vmware-deploy.INPROGRESS (No such file or directory) 

EXIT STATE Done 

Setting deploy error: Error removing lock /tmp/.vmware-deploy.Done (No such file or directory) 

EXIT STATE ERRORED 

Setting deploy error: Error removing lock /tmp/.vmware-deploy.ERRORED (No such file or directory) 

Setting deploy error: Success. 

Deploying cabinet file /tmp/vmware-root/709d2d0c/cust93117962197543457.cab. 

Transitioning from state (null) to state INPROGRESS. 

ENTER STATE INPROGRESS 

Reading cabinet file /tmp/vmware-root/709d2d0c/cust93117962197543457.cab. 

Creating directory /tmp
Creating directory /tmp/.vmware
Creating directory /tmp/.vmware/linux
Creating directory /tmp/.vmware/linux/deploy
Extracting package files. 

Launching deployment /usr/bin/perl -I/tmp/.vmware/linux/deploy/scripts /tmp/.vmware/linux/deploy/scripts/Customize.pl /tmp/.vmware/linux/deploy/cust.cfg. 

Command to exec : /usr/bin/perl 

sizeof ProcessInternal is 56

Returning, pending output from stdout
Returning, pending output from stderr
Process exited normally after 0 seconds, returned 127
No more output from stdout
No more output from stderr
Customization command output: 

Customization process returned with error. 

Deployment result = 127 

Setting generic error status in vmx. 

Transitioning from state INPROGRESS to state ERRORED. 

ENTER STATE ERRORED 

EXIT STATE INPROGRESS 

Setting deploy error: Deployment failed. The forked off process returned error code. 

Deployment failed. The forked off process returned error code. 

No nics to enable.

Launching cleanup. 

Command to exec : /bin/rm 

sizeof ProcessInternal is 56

Returning, pending output from stdout
Returning, pending output from stderr
Process exited normally after 0 seconds, returned 0
No more output from stdout
No more output from stderr
Customization command output: 

Deploy error: Deployment failed. The forked off process returned error code. 

Package deploy failed in DeployPkg_DeployPackageFromFile
## Closing log
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: This is a good question. Are you using vCloud Director from a service provider?

Comment: I would just `yum install open-vm-tools` myself..

Comment: Yes, it's a service provider.

Comment: open-vm-tools is installed. Posting answer now. Somehow perl was corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I poked at the image a bit more and noticed that the perl executables were both 0 kb. I have no idea how that happened, but I'm willing to blame several of my failed tests and reboots.

For future reference, and for folks who want full control of packages from the ISO, this should get you up and running. This will also create a working template without requiring Internet (yum) access...

```
# Run minimal install
# Reboot
# Re-insert installation ISO
mkdir -p /media/cdrom
mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
cd /media/cdrom/Packages

# Install perl and all dependencies
rpm -Uvh perl-5.16.3-286.el7.x86_64.rpm perl-Carp-1.26-244.el7.noarch.rpm perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64.rpm perl-Exporter-5.68-3.el7.noarch.rpm perl-File-Path-2.09-2.el7.noarch.rpm perl-File-Temp-0.23.01-3.el7.noarch.rpm perl-Filter-1.49-3.el7.x86_64.rpm perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-2.el7.noarch.rpm perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.033-3.el7.noarch.rpm perl-PathTools-3.40-5.el7.x86_64.rpm perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-286.el7.noarch.rpm perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch.rpm perl-Pod-Simple-3.28-4.el7.noarch.rpm perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch.rpm perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.27-248.el7.x86_64.rpm perl-Socket-2.010-3.el7.x86_64.rpm perl-Storable-2.45-3.el7.x86_64.rpm perl-Text-ParseWords-3.29-4.el7.noarch.rpm perl-Time-HiRes-1.9725-3.el7.x86_64.rpm perl-Time-Local-1.2300-2.el7.noarch.rpm perl-constant-1.27-2.el7.noarch.rpm perl-libs-5.16.3-286.el7.x86_64.rpm perl-macros-5.16.3-286.el7.x86_64.rpm perl-parent-0.225-244.el7.noarch.rpm perl-podlators-2.5.1-3.el7.noarch.rpm perl-threads-1.87-4.el7.x86_64.rpm perl-threads-shared-1.43-6.el7.x86_64.rpm

# Install open-vm-tools and dependencies
rpm -Uvh open-vm-tools-9.10.2-4.el7.x86_64.rpm libdnet-1.12-13.1.el7.x86_64.rpm libicu-50.1.2-15.el7.x86_64.rpm libmspack-0.5-0.4.alpha.el7.x86_64.rpm net-tools-2.0-0.17.20131004git.el7.x86_64.rpm

cd
umount /media/cdrom

# vmtoolsd is enabled, but you can start it to verify that vCloud picks it up
systemctl start vmtoolsd

# stop the VM
# customize via vCloud - I changed hostname and did a simple configuration script
#   that echos to a file to make sure things are working
# vApps > Virtual Machines > Power On and Force Recustomization
# log in and verify updated hostname, new file that was echoed, and possibly
#   new IP if you were set to DHCP
```

Comment: And yes, you could create a /media/cdrom baseurl repo file instead of running rpm with a thousand packages.

Comment: One more note - You do need to change /etc/redhat-release for CentOS7.2, but the above steps work for that as well.